# Network not working after i close lid of Dell XPS 9550

Tags: wifi, networking, ethernet

So, i have a 2016 Dell XPS 9550, 4K screen , i7, 32gb Ram and a 1TB M2 SSD. Elementary runs blazingly fast as my native OS. But i have a small bug, when i either have my dell dock plugged in via USB that has Ethernet or on WiFi, if i shut the lid of the laptop and don't shutdown, when i open it back up, all networking has stopped, even though it says I'm connected.

I've tried sudo services networking restart, and logging out and back in and nothing, the only fix is a reboot....

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 2):

With Ubuntu 16.10 on the XPS 9550 I have the same trouble.  Running the following command after opening the lid fixes the problem for me.  There should be no need to log out and log back in after running the command.

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

The [Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/power-suspendfail.html#hardware) seems to say the source of the problem lies in the driver.

Answer (score 0):

Mine does this occasionally. I created a script and desk so I created an executable script and Slingshot menu launcher so I wouldn't have to use the command line each time. This is what I did:

Create a new file in Scratch

```
#!/bin/bash

service network-manager restart
```

Save it off as whatever name you want with a .sh extension.

Make it executable by running

```
chmod +x networkrestartscript.sh <---insert the file name you gave it
```

You can then create a menu launcher to run the script with a click by creating a .desktop file and saving it in ~/.local/share/applications. The launcher will then show up in your Slingshot menu and you can lock it to the Plank if you like.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Network Restart
Comment=Network Restart
Exec=/home/elementary/Tools/Scripts/network-restart.sh
Icon=/usr/share/icons/elementaryPlus/emblems/16/emblem-insync-syncing.svg
Categories=Utility
Terminal=false
```